# Obligatory elisions

Tags: orthography, articles

I have read the following sentence:

> È una azione molto strana.

Isn't the elision obligatory between the feminine indefinite article and a word starting with a vowel? Which elisions are obligatory?

Comment: That's indeed a weird phrase, especially with a word starting with "a": I guess nobody would normally pronunciate a double "a" sound while saying "un'azione".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Vittorio Coletti, elision is compulsory in singular determinative articles before vowel and also in feminine  indeterminative article and numeral *"una"* (and its compounds) before vowel. In his book *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto*, this linguist explains:

> Negli articoli determinativi singolari davanti a vocale l'elisione è obbligatoria, mentre nei pronomi personali, pur in quelli identici agli articoli (*lo*, *la*), è facoltativa: «l'amore/l'amo, lo amo»; «l'attesa/l'attende, la attende»; «l'importanza/t'importa, ti importa»; «l'udito/l'ho udito, lo ho udito». Non elide ormai più l'articolo femminile plurale («le amiche», «delle eccezioni»), né quello maschile plurale *gli*, neppure davanti a *i* («gli inglesi», «degli italiani»). 
>   
>   [...] 
>   
>         L'elisione è frequente anche con l'articolo indeterminativo e col numerale femminile *una* (e composti, come si vedrà al cap. IV) davanti a vocale, per cui, anche se troppo spesso ce ne dimentichiamo (lo dimostrano molti errori di ortografia nella ricerca di Serianni e Benedetti), si deve scrivere «un'amica», «un'epoca», «c'erano solo un'anziana e due gatti», «qualcun'altra».

And some pages later:

> Stessa distribuzione di *il/lo* per l'articolo indeterminativo *un/uno*, meno l'elisione davanti al maschile perché si tratta di un troncamento («un cane», «un treno», «un amico», «uno stato»), mentre l'elisione è obbligatoria al femminile davanti a vocale *una/un'* («una casa», «un'amica»).

This author also explains that one must elide particle "ci" before forms of verb "essere" and "andare" beginning by vowel:

> Naturalmente ci sono ancora casi stabili di elisione oltre quella degli articoli determinativi singolari. Ad esempio, la particella *ci* che attualizza e modifica il significato di *essere* (*c'è*,  *c'era*) e di *entrare* («lui non c'entra») elide obbligatoriamente, nel parlato e nello scritto; invece, quando fa lo stesso con *avere*, elide nel parlato, ma nello scritto no: «c'ho fame» si dice, ma si scrive «ci ho fame», per evitare di indurre la lettura «*k'ò fame» o, anche se è meno fastidioso, l'uso dell'apostrofo davanti ad *h*, come abbiamo appena fatto.

Comment: Is there no consensus about this grammar subject? Should I believe in Treccani or Vittorio Coletti?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: I don't think there is a contradiction between what is said by Treccani and Coletti: it's simply that the explanations by Coletti are more concrete and detailed.

Comment: How isn't there a contradiction? Treccani explicitly says that the elision "is not mandatory in an absolute sense in any of these words" (articles lo, la, una, some adjectives, some conjunctions, pronouns, adverbs, prepositions) and Coletti says that the elision "is mandatory in the singular definite article" . Also, if I understood it right, Coletti also says that the elision is mandatory in the feminine indefinite article (although confusingly at first it says it is *often* used). Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista:  "In nessuna di queste parole" refers to "in alcune congiunzioni e in alcuni aggettivi, pronomi, avverbi, preposizioni".

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying it! I had read it differently. "A and B are normal, C and D are frequent. None of these are mandatory." is an ambiguous statement.

Comment: Regarding articles ("lo", "la", "una"), Treccani uses "normale" which maybe is not the best word  (it is somewhat ambiguous), but I interpret it as standard in nowadays Italian.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer in [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/elisione/) after researching a little more. According to it, the elision:

(original text)

> è normale negli articoli lo, la, una davanti a vocale e nelle preposizioni articolate composte con lo, la; è antico o letterario nell’articolo le e nelle preposizioni articolate composte con le. È inoltre frequente in alcune congiunzioni e in alcuni aggettivi, pronomi, avverbi, preposizioni. Non è obbligatoria in senso assoluto in nessuna di queste parole, ma è più frequente con alcune (questo, quello, di, si, ci, pronome o avverbio, davanti a vocale palatale), molto meno con altre (pronomi personali).

(text translated to English)

> is normal in the articles "lo", "la", "una" before a vowel and in articulated prepositions composed with "lo", "la"; it is ancient or literary in the article "le" and in the articulated prepositions composed with "le". It is also frequent in some conjunctions and in some adjectives, pronouns, adverbs, prepositions. It is not mandatory in an absolute sense in any of these words, but it is more frequent with some of them ("questo", "quello", "di", "si", "ci", pronoun or adverb, before a palatal vowel), much less with others (personal pronouns).